# Integrate TIBCO EMS with JBoss 5.0

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, hornetq, tibco, tibco-ems

I need to integrate Tibco EMS with JBoss 5.0. The biggest problem is JBoss is shipped with Hornetq which i want to replace with Tibco. Tried searching a lot for a proper documentation but no sucess, few of the docs available on JBoss Forum are not proper. Can someone provide link for the same?

Comment: My application is not using MDBs, hence all i want is to know how to make tibco available for the JNDI lookup

Answer (score 0):

The TIBCO EMS Initial Factory is `com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory`

You may need theses properties:

```
QueueFactory = QueueConnectionFactory
TopicFactory = TopicConnectionFactory`
```